# How can I wipe my Samsung galaxy S5 completely before selling it?

Tags: samsung

I has a Samsung Galaxy S5 and now i want to sell it to others.This phone takes many my private information. How can i delete them all and ensure that no one can restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try factory reset first, after that using some random data to over-written. If you worry about that it can be completely over-written. Try some eraser software, which will help users to clean up the exist data and the deleted data together.